# Local git config in git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

My repository structure:

```
repo_a
└── repo_b
    └── .gitconfig
```

`repo_b` is a submodule.
`.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    b = branch
```

How can I add the path of `.gitconfig` such that only `repo_b` can use it?

Expected output:

```
$ cd repo_a
$ git b
git: 'b' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
$ cd repo_b
$ git b
* master
```

Edit #1:

The answers from @jthill and @bk2204 are good.
They describe how to access the config file for the submodule using:

```
git rev-parse --git-path config
```

I want to specify what I want.
I want the changes in the `.gitconfig` file in `repo_b` to be tracked by git. Such that when cloning only `repo_b` I would also have access to the same `.gitconfig`.
The solution from @jthill does seem possible. However, it does also seem quite error-prone, and I would have to add a hook for every single change in git that might change the `.gitconfig`. Such as `git pull`, `git checkout`, `git merge`.

Thus my question would have 2 parts:

1. How can I both track changes for `repo/.gitconfig` and use it as a local config file?
2. How can I implement said functionality for both a normal repo and within a submodule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not implement this feature because of security concerns.

I decided to use a separate configuration file in JSON and store the values I needed there.
Thus I could parse the config file when needed instead of using git.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the equivalent of `.git/config` for a submodule, then the easiest way to find it is to run `git rev-parse --git-path config` from within `repo_b`.  That's the easiest way to set up configuration for a local repository.

You can't put a `.gitconfig` file into a repository and expect it to be used; it's not secure to share configuration in a repository, so Git doesn't allow it.

If you want to edit the local configuration with `git config`, you can do that by changing into `repo_b`.

Comment: Thanks, this made it easier to find the config file, however, does not quite solve my problem, refer to "Edit #1" in my question.

Comment: What you are asking for is unsupported by Git because it's a security problem.  Conffig can contain arbitrary programs to run, and allowing repositories to ship config would allow someone who can modify a repository to execute arbitrary code on the system of anyone who cloned it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible:

Reading [the section of the Git manual corresponding to the configuration of submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_the_configuration_of_submodules), it seems that the 2 possible options are:

- Creating a file called `config` in the root of the submodule
- Adding content to the `.gitmodules` file of the superproject

I tried to add an alias in both of these files and the alias did not take effect.

**Edit:**

Actually, now that I am taking the time to think, it makes sense that this would not be possible since the code for git-submodule was not written  with the idea that you would run git commands from within a submodule, but instead, directly from the superproject.

If you run your git commands for your submodule from within the submodule, then you are not making use of the submodule functionality. In that case, you might be better off creating a normal repo within your superproject and add its path to the `.gitignore` file of the superproject. Probably better though would be to learn to handle the submodule from the superproject.

Answer (score 0):

As a smoketest, you can have people using the repo do

```
cat .gitconfig >>$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/config
```

and that will append your configs to the repository setup.  For a safer version,

```
sed -si '/^# --repo-b-config--$/,/^# --repo-b-config--$/d; $r .gitconfig' \
        $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/config
```

and have `# --repo-b-config--` lines at the top and bottom of your special fil.

Git intentionally does not allow fetch to override administrative choices. There is no way to make fetch usurp anything. Your repository is yours. You decide what happens in it, and that means nobody else gets to sneak anything in unless you build the pathway for them yourself.  You can run arbitrary commands on checkout to update the local config or anything else, but in your repository, in every repository you administer (including for instance every repo you create with `git clone` or `git init` or `git submodule update --init`) you control what those commands are.

So if you want to have the above `sed` run after every checkout, put (a possibly-fixed-up version of) it in that repo's  `hooks/post-checkout` and you'll have what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this made it easier to find the config file. I do think this might work if I manage to cover all hooks that are relevant. However, as I specified in "Edit #1" in my question, I do prefer if I can find a less error-prone solution.

Comment: Git doesn't make this easy to do because it's a bad idea. If you want to run a repo-local shipped alias/script, admit that's what you're doing and do it. Conflating git and the code histories it's managing is a recipe for bad surprises..

Comment: Yeah, I decided to no use this approach to my original problem in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you just `cd` into the submodule and use something like:

```
git config user.name "Jon Doe"
```

You'll see that git will add that config to your root repository under `.git/modules/<your-submodule-name>/config`

You could use that file to set any specific config for your submodule.